# The result of a calculation is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, math, xhtml, calculator

This program is supposed to calculate the pixel density of a screen but when I hit the Calculate PPI button, nothing seems to happen. The Width, Height and Screen Size are supposed to be horizontal resolution in pixels, vertical resolution in pixels and diagonal screen size in inches respectively. Could anyone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it?

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style> #ppi { border:none; }
body { font-family:yu gothic; }
 </style>

<body>
<p>
  <label for="Width">Width</label>
  <input type="text" name="Width" id="Width">
  <label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ScreenSize">Screen Size</label>
  <input type="text" name="ScreenSize" id="ScreenSize">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Calculate PPI" onClick="calc()">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="PPI">PPI</label>
  <input type="text" name="PPI" id="ppi">
</p>

<script>
function calc() {
var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("Width")),
h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height")),
s = parseFloat("10.00")(document.getElementById("ScreenSize")),
ppi = (w*w) + (h*h);
ppi = Math.sqrt(ppi);
ppi = ppi/s;`enter code here`
document.getElementById("ppi").value = ppi;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `parseInt` and `parseFloat` to return when parsing a HTML element? Though this line: `s = parseFloat("10.00")(doc...)` breaks your code.

Comment: I'm afriad I didn't understand your question. I'm a newbie in JS :(

Comment: Those functions expect a string, and you're passing a HTML element, this results `NaN`. Then there's something odd when you're assigning a value to `s`.

Comment: This is not returning anything. I once changed that float part to integer and once changed all of them to float. Both of them or either one of them returned NaN. However the current code doesn't return even that.

Comment: Umh... user1823 has fixed your issues. Can't you see anything odd on the line `s=...`? That causes an error, and you will not get any result. Practically on that line you're doing this: `10(document.getElementById("ScreenSize"));`

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Yes the issue is fixed. However can you tell me how to display the result in upto 2 decimal places for this code?

Comment: Use either [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) or [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

Comment: I used it earlier but the result stopped displaying. Could you please tell me specific to my code that how and where to use the method?

Comment: Those methods return a string, hence use them as late as possible. `document.getElementById("ppi").value = ppi.toFixed(2);`. Please consider to accept the given answer, if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `onClick`. Instead, it should be `onclick`. Also, you are calculating parseFloat of `"10.00"`, which is just `10`. Lastly, you are trying to parseInt the **element** of `width` and `height`; you need to get the **`.value`** of the elements.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style> #ppi { border:none; }
body { font-family:yu gothic; }
 </style>

<body>
<p>
  <label for="Width">Width</label>
  <input type="text" name="Width" id="width">
  <label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ScreenSize">Screen Size</label>
  <input type="text" name="ScreenSize" id="ScreenSize">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Calculate PPI" onclick="calc()">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="PPI">PPI</label>
  <input type="text" name="PPI" id="ppi">
</p>

<script>
function calc() {
var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("width").value),
h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value),
s = 10*parseInt(document.getElementById("ScreenSize").value);
ppi = (w*w) + (h*h);
ppi = Math.sqrt(ppi);
ppi = ppi/s;
document.getElementById("ppi").value = ppi;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ImranMakhdoom if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? It gives **you** reputation too, thanks!